# Coun(*),distinct and column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How to accomplish like this in sqlserver

```
select firstname,count(*) from
(select distinct firstname,lastname,amount 
from emp)
group by firstname
```

This works in oracle.

Comment: It's always helpful to say what your actual problem is. In this case, what happens when you run your query in SQL Server? Do you get an error, or the wrong results, or what precisely happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand what are you trying to do, but your query could be written this way:

```
SELECT firstname, COUNT(*) 
FROM emp
GROUP BY firstname;
```

**Or:**

```
select firstname, count(*) 
from 
(
  select distinct firstname, lastname, amount 
  from emp
) AS t
group by firstname;
```

You can also use the `DISTINCT` keyword inside the `COUNT`; something like this: `COUNT(DISTINCT columnanme)` instead.

---

**Or:**

```
select firstname, lastname, amount, COUNT(*)
from emp
group by firstname, lastname, amount;
```

Comment: Not those are not the same.  jim smith 10, jim smith 10   The first select would count 2 and the second count 1.

Comment: @Blam - Yes you are right, they might be differ, but the OP didn't explain what he is trying to achieve, so I give him different alternatives.

Comment: Thanks, this exactly what I need.It is the second query which works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example from some stuff where I work that does basically the same thing:

```
SELECT SYS_CSL, COUNT(SYS_CSL)
FROM (
    SELECT SYS_CSL 
    FROM [VANTAGE_READ].CSL_SERV_RANK
    WHERE AGNT_CSL = 0
    AND (STOP_DTE_CSL > GETDATE() OR STOP_DTE_CSL IS NULL)
    ) t1 GROUP BY sys_csl
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to name the derived table

```
select firstname, count(*)  
from  (select distinct firstname,lastname,amount from emp) derived 
group by firstname
```